# Redis Key Space Notifications Unexpected end of stream Error for High Volume of Events

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to explore redis keyspace notifications and its implementation in springboot for using the redis keyspace notifications for ttl use case. I am trying to test the scale at which this can work, when I used smaller volume like 10k-100k keys its working fine with out any issue. But when I increase the keys that expire at a particular time to 500k I am getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unexpected end of stream.; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:65) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:192) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.doWithJedis(JedisConnection.java:836) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.pSubscribe(JedisConnection.java:741) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$Subscriber.doSubscribe(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:1231) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$BlockingSubscriber.lambda$eventuallyPerformSubscription$2(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:1433) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readLongCrLf(RedisInputStream.java:154) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readIntCrLf(RedisInputStream.java:148) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processBulkReply(Protocol.java:188) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:170) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processMultiBulkReply(Protocol.java:221) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:172) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:230) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:352) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getUnflushedObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:314) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisPubSub.process(BinaryJedisPubSub.java:101) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisPubSub.proceedWithPatterns(BinaryJedisPubSub.java:89) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.psubscribe(BinaryJedis.java:3900) ~[jedis-3.8.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.lambda$pSubscribe$7(JedisConnection.java:746) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.doWithJedis(JedisConnection.java:834) ~[spring-data-redis-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
... 4 common frames omitted
```

I have implemented a simple Redis event listner to capture the expired keys, code like below.

```
package com.example.rediseventlistnertest.listner;

import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.Message;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class EventTimeOutListner implements MessageListener {

public List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
    String key = new String(message.getBody());
    Date date = new Date();
    Long sec = date.getTime();
    String d = date.toString();
    keys.add(key);
    log.info("expired key: {}, expired at {} {} {}", key, sec, date, keys.size());
}
}
```

Above class is for capturing the key and the below one for listening to redis keyspace notifications

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {


@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory, EventTimeOutListner taskTimeoutListener, TimeOutListner tol) {

    RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setMaxSubscriptionRegistrationWaitingTime(10000);
    try {
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        listenerContainer.addMessageListener(taskTimeoutListener,
                new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired"));
        log.info("size of  keys : {}",  taskTimeoutListener.keys.size());
        //listenerContainer.addMessageListener(tol,
        //        new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired"));
        listenerContainer.setErrorHandler(
                e -> log.error("Error in redisMessageListenerContainer", e));
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.info("Something went worng exception is : {}",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        return listenerContainer;
    }
}

}
```

I tried adding pooling and increasing the no of connections etc but no luck the error still persists and I am not able to figure what could be the exact reason for the issue, did any one face the simlar issue, what could be the possible issue and what can be done to avoid this failure and scale redis for larger volumes of key space notificaitons.

Answer (score 0):

I tried exploring the internet for possible reasons for this issue, I figured out that one of the reason for this is maximum output that redis allows is the reason for this failure.

In redis configuration there is something called client-output-buffer-limit which limit what is the maximum data output that redis alows for different cases as

Redis Output buffer has following limits

1. For normal operations set, get etc there is no limit
2. For Pub Sub Mechanism there is default hard limit of 32Mb and soft limit of 8mb for 60 seconds
3. For replication mechanism it has default hard limit of 256Mb and soft limit of 64mb for 60 seconds

However these can be configured to bigger values which allows high volumes of data output, you can change the values by identifying the path of redis config file and updating the value of the output buffer limit of the Pub Sub mechanism by changing the value configured for attribute

> client-output-buffer-limit pubsub

By updating this redis allows larger output buffer.